# Determine if std::string has all unique characters [C++]

Tags: c++, std

I have what appears to be a really simple solution:

```
void determineStringUnique(std::string str) {
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); //sort characters
    std::unique(str.begin(), str.end()); //remove duplicate characters in a row (why we did std::sort right before)
    std::cout << str.size() << std::endl;
}
```

(I realize this function isn't complete yet, I'm just investigating the size after std::unique. The thing left to do is to check whether the new size is equal to the original size - if so, then there are only unique characters).

But when I print out str.size(), it always is equal to the original string length. After some debugging I find that std::unique removes the expected (repeated) characters, but there is always some place in the string where some characters are added, etc. and I cannot figure out why.

Here is an example input: "abcdefghijklmnopabc". After std::sort, I get "aabbccdefghijklmnop", as expected. But after std::unique, I get "abcdefghijklmnopnop", which means it added "nop" at the end, but did get rid of the extra a, b, and c at the beginning.

If anyone has an answer to this, it will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Given the small size of a typical string, `return std::set<char>(str.begin(), str.end()).size() == str.size();` would probably be fine.

Comment: I think this is the best method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you mentioned, `std::unique()` does not actually remove elements, it just shuffles them around.  It has a return value...

```
int countUniqueCharacters(std::string str)
{
    // e.g. str = "abcdefabc"
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end());
    // e.g. str = "aabbccdef"
    auto i = std::unique(str.begin(), str.end());
    // e.g. str = "abcdef???" with i pointing to first "?"
    // (in other words, i = str.begin() + 6)
    // Note that "?" is an unknown character, not an actual question mark
    return i - str.begin();
    // returns 6
}
```

The `str::unique()` function

Answer (score 2):

`unique` is overkill, there's a function which does precisely what you want.

```
void determineStringUnique(std::string str) {
    std::sort(str.begin(), str.end()); //sort characters
    std::cout << std::adjacent_find(str.begin(), str.end()) == str.end << std::endl;
}
```